# Where and When to Prune Damaged Young Tree

Tags: trees, pruning, tree-care, maple

I foolishly removed a protective cage around a young tree in my yard over the winter and a buck girdled it. My understanding is the portion above the girdle needs to be removed for the tree to recover properly. I'm not sure if I should prune above all healthy bark (purple), directly above the healthy bark (green), or somewhere in between (blue).

[image]

Does where I make the cut matter? And is the end of winter the best time to do this?

Comment: Its not clear to me where the tree was girdled (did you mean girdled - ie ripping the bark off all round the tree at a specific height)  - but a couple of thoughts/comments - (1) Why not wait for spring and see where you get new growth comes and cut it above that  and (2) you don't want to cut as low down as the green line.  There looks to be a graft about 1/4 of the way above the green line between the green line and blue line - and if you cut it below that point any growth you get will be the rootstock and likely not what you want.

Comment: A general rule of thumb is that if the bark is removed from up to 75% of a tree's trunk then the tree will come back. This is species-dependent - I've seen a ginkgo and a chokecherry nearly completely girdled (85%+) regrow just fine. Wait until spring, as @davidgo mentioned. Should growth occur above the damage, do nothing to the trunk where the bark has been rubbed off - it needs to stay open to the elements, so no coverings of any kind. Any protection should be athe fence you have or 1/4" steel mesh fence (AKA hardware cloth) formed into a cylinder and staked into place.

Comment: The tree has 100% bark loss in an area between the blue and purple lines (hard to see given the lighting). Thanks, both of you. I will wait to see what grows before making my next move.